# knn or other method to select class with highest number of points that are closest to target

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

Let us say I have thousands of points on a 2D axis, and a class for each point (100s of classes) and for some points there's only one class.

Then I have a single coordinate (xTarget,yTarget) and I do not want to assign it to a given class but rather assign a score for each of the classes in terms of how close the class centroid (calculated as if all points have equal weight) is to the target point.  The tricky part is that the problem doesn't end there, I'd also want to select classes that has the most number of points belonging to them.  Maybe have a parameter to tweak between how close to the centroid the target points need to be and how many points i want to have for each class to be relevant.

Do you have suggestions in terms of algo's (knn comes to mind) that could help, specifically in the following stages:
(1) Compute class centroid with all points having same weight
(2) Score how relevant a class is to the target point as a mix between how many points are in that class and how close the centroid is to the target point

Comment: Why don't you just do classic kNN, without hoping that the centroids are a good approximation?

Comment: I wonder if you might be better served by a probabilistic classifier (which returns a probability of membership in each class), rather than an ad hoc solution. For example, your 'distance to centroids' and 'points per class' sound vaguely like the conditional distributions and prior class probabilities of a generative model (e.g. Naive Bayes), which would then be combined using Bayes rule to give class membership probabilities. Could you say more about your underlying goal?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse in my understanding classic kNN objective is to create the optimal boundaries for each class, but in this case my objective is to have a measure for a target point, in terms of how close it is to the centroid of that class and for that class to have as many observations as possible.

Comment: @user20160 the goal is to assign a score to a target point in terms of membership to a given group of points in 2D (or higher dimensions).  I don't just care about membership but I also want to select groups of points that have larger number of observations.  I.e., the target point may belong really well to a group of two points and not as good to a group of 100 points ... but the tradeoff needs to be considered there since it may be more beneficial to assign it to the larger group.

Comment: knn does not optimize any boundary. It just looks at the distances and labels of neighbors.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse this is true, my mistake.